A question about a possible electrical wring terminal/component
In an enclosure I have to wire several modules such as relays power supplies, PCB modules ect. But it gets messy with wirings especially if a part requires many connections at its screw terminals and many wire inputs even at one terminal.
As an example see this photo from the enclosure showing how relay is wired:

See how  many wires are entering into relay socket terminals. Many wires into a single input as well. When there are several parts it looks more messy in the enclosure. I also have to use terminal busses to connect all grounds.
Is there a typical part or terminal used for such cases to make things less messy and more prepositional? Unfortunately these type of info cannot be found in books so as a last resort I wated to ask here.
Edit:
(The enclosure is powered by 12V DC supply so there is no 230V inside it. But currents can be up to 5A.)
Another view:

Here is the wiring schematic of the relay socket:

Can you see my trouble?
It is this relay socket. How can I make this wiring look neater? Is there a type of terminal that would translate those relay socket terminals into another terminal bar to make it look more tidier? Or is it how it is and cant do anything about it?

Rule #1: use correct wire lengths. Doesn't look like the case in the picture, which is clearly wired by a layman. Another simple trick and widely common practice is to "braid" wires of signals/supply belonging together, essentially just twist them around each other. This will make the installation tidier and help out a little bit against EMI all at once. Do not use wires for mechanical purposes though, like making knots with them or using them as if they are ropes.

Also what the heck is that wire doing underneath the relay socket? :) I'm not sure why there is a hole there, but likely it is either meant as an air gap to prevent creepage or it's some plastics molding thing.

Please see my edit for more details.


Figure 1. A sample control panel in progress. Note that trunking covers have not been installed yet. Source Go Switchgear.
Standard panel-building:

Mount components on DIN rail where possible.
Separate high voltage / high current to one area of the panel if possible.
Most terminals can handle one or two wires. Never try to put three in. Instead wire from terminal to terminal without branches.
Use trunking top and bottom. For small panels and where space is tight, omit the trunking, route the wires neatly with nice right-angle bends and bundle them with cable ties. This generally requires cutting wires to exact length.
If required for power distribution, use terminals with jumper bars that allow you to parallel connect as many as required without external wire loops.
Don't take shortcuts with the wire. If it needs to connect from a terminal on the bottom of a component to the top, then send it the long way around through the trunking or cable loom.
Use a wire colour standard. There are many!
Labelling the wires isn't essential but can save many headaches.


I tried to clarify more. please see my edit for more details.

There are some photos of a neat layout on https://aic-controls.com/relays-applied-industrial-controls/. You need to develop a neater wiring style. It's a skill.

• Don't leave your screwdriver in at the end of the installation. // Somewhere in Norfolk there is a ceiling tile with a nice pair of flush cutters behind it :(

You already have a DIN rail so you can use terminal and/or power distribution blocks. At 5A, you should be able to use standard terminal blocks like these:

All the terminal sizes are the same and you can add jumpers into that "trench" in the middle to connect them together.
For more fan-out, you can get a power distribution block like this:

You can see that there is one large connection that fans out (or in) to several smaller ones.
Both photos from Phoenix Contact.
